# The event ‘System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement.MediaOpened’ can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Tags: c#, winforms, events, compiler-errors

please help me some error is display for this line:

```
mediaElement1.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement1.MediaOpened);
```

Error:

> Error 1 The event ‘System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement.MediaOpened’ can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Please help me how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, you're placing `mediaElement1.MediaOpened` on the right-hand side:

```
mediaElement1.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement1.MediaOpened);
                                                    ^
                                                    //Can't place it here
```

You'll need to create the `RoutedEventHandler` in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to events, such as MediaOpened, the += operator is used to add a delegate/method to take some action on said event.

In this case you're interested in the MediaOpened event so you'll want something like:

```
mediaElement1.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnMediaOpened);

private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO - Handle the MediaOpened event here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are actually trying to do. if you wanna do some logic when mediaElement1.MediaOpened event occur, then you need to create a method and put your code to do the logic in that method.

```
private void mediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Put your logic here
}
```

Then register above method to handle mediaElement1.MediaOpened event with one of the following code

```
//option 1: just like your existing code with correction
mediaElement1.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement1_MediaOpened);

//option 2: brief version of option 1
mediaElement1.MediaOpened += mediaElement1_MediaOpened;

//option 3: register in xaml instead of c#
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1" MediaOpened="mediaElement1_MediaOpened"/>
```